# Is this intersection even possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

This is a question regarding vectors I got for homework:

> A, B and C are three points in the plane that are not on one line. Let
> us denote the center of BC by P. Point Q is on the line segment AC
> such that AQ : QC = 1 : 3. Using vectors, determine the intersection R
> of line segment PQ with line segment AB and determine the ratio AR :
> BR.

The only way I could find to answer this question is if, both PQ and AB are not actually line segments,therefore making the intersection possible.
Is the question incorrectly worded, or is there a solution?

Comment: I think the  question incorrectly worded indeed, and "intersection of *line segments*" (PQ and AB) should be replaced by "intersection of *lines*".

Comment: @ACB What does $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ mean?

Comment: Intersection of line segments is particular case of intersection of lines. You could solve the problem for intersection of lines and then show that there is no intersection of line segments.